# Launch screen(image view) fade out

Tags: android, webview, imageview, fadeout

I have made a launch screen for my app which makes a Imageview visible for 4 seconds after launch. Then it switches the visibility of the Imageview and the web view so that the web view is now visible. How can i make a fadeout effect when the Imageview disappears?

This is the code I use for switching the visibility

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.webMain).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 4000);
```

Comment: Why have you done this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is that `Handler().postdelayed(Runnable, int)` waits for the specified time and then executes the `Runnable`. What you need to do is to change the transparency of the views.

To fade one view in while fading another out, try this:

First set the `WebView` to fade in over 4 seconds:

```
View web = findViewById(R.id.webMain);

web.setAlpha(0f);
web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

web.animate()
        .alpha(1f)
        .setDuration(4000)
        .setListener(null);
```

Next set the `ImageView` to fade out:

```
View image = findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1);
image.animate()
        .alpha(0f)
        .setDuration(4000)
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                // Now that the ImageView is fully transparent, hide it.
                image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

The two views should crossfade evenly. See [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html) at Android Developers for more info and an animation.

Hope this helps!